# SQL Find Record in Table A not in Table B

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have Tbl1

[image]

and Tbl2

[image]

I would like to return the record that is in A but not in B, in this case I would like to return the bottom 2 records.

I have tried the following but this yields 0 records. What am I missing?

```
SELECT tbl2.field1, tbl2.field2, tbl2.field3
FROM tbl2
RIGHT JOIN tbl1
ON tbl2.field1 = tbl1.field1
WHERE tbl1.field1 IS NULL
```

EDIT:

I have tried LEFT join and I have also tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl2
LEFT JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.field1 = tbl2.field1
WHERE tbl1.field1 IS NULL
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: I have tried that, empty fields. I am wondering if this is because there is no unique identifier (primary key)? I don't really know much about SQL.. @mrNone

Comment: Because all `field1` values in `Tab1` and `Tab2` are `550`. Try use `ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** **solution:** You can use the **not exists** method the check the second table.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM tbl1
              WHERE tbl1.field1 = tbl2.field1
              AND tbl1.field2 = tbl2.field2
              AND tbl1.field3 = tbl2.field3);
```

The both tables have the same fields, because of that, we have to check all fields (like mentoined by @Andre).

Comment: I get an empty table with field headings 'tbl2.ID', 'tbl2.field1', 'tbl2.field2', 'tbl2.field3' and so on for tbl1

Comment: Yes I tried it you are right, but I found another better solution. Try the edited solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You need **all** columns you want to compare in the JOIN condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl2
LEFT JOIN tbl1 
  ON (tbl1.field1 = tbl2.field1) AND (tbl1.field2 = tbl2.field2) AND (tbl1.field3 = tbl2.field3) 
WHERE tbl1.field1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Not sure why either, this answer also works! I tried to accept both as answers (clearly I'm  not very stackoverflow savvy) but it could only accept one. I've just upvoted this one instead.

Comment: :-) Yes, both solutions should be equivalent. If you have large tables (many thousand records), you may want to compare their performance. @Al3x